# Weight Solr score by a non-search field

Tags: solr

I have included a field in my schema that is not a field being searched on, but I want to weight the results by the integer value of that field.

I'm struggling to see in the documentation anywhere how to do this?  Is this behaviour implemented at query stage or index stage, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Field based Boosting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#Field_Based_Boosting) which can allow you to boost your results based on a field.
The field need not be the field being searched upon.

You can also you [Index time boosts](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#index-time_boosts) for the fields

e.g. [How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents)

If you are using [Dismax](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser) you can use [boost query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29) or [boost function](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bf_.28Boost_Functions.29).

[Use Document boost for multiplying the score](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html)

> At indexing, users can specify that certain documents are more
>   important than others, by assigning a document boost. For this, the
>   score of each document is also multiplied by its boost value
>   doc-boost(d).

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I can't see how you add relative weight though.  An optional query has a binary effect, but I would effectively want to multiple the relevance score by the integer.

Comment: try document boost. Updated the answer.